# How to throw compile time exception, if certain value is not set.

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

I have created an Android library, there is a method `setContext()`in it. Client need to pass context other wise app will crash at runtime. I need to throw an error on compile time, if user does not set context. I can't pass it throw constructor as its a `singleton` class.

**Client**

```
SampleLibrary sl= SampleLibrary.getInstance();
sl.setContext(this);
```

**Class**

```
public void setContext(Context context){
  this.context= context; 
}
```

Kindly guide me How to throw compile time exception, if certain value is not set or null.

Comment: what you're asking is not doable, what you could have is an alert that tells you that the variable might be null

Answer (score 2):

doing this

```
sl.setContext(this);
```

is giving the option to developers to dont set the context, or forget to set it...

but if you define the class as

public `SampleLibrary(Context ctx)` then they are done! there is no other chance for them to create an object of **SampleLibrary** without giving a context

Answer (score 0):

Avoid setting Context in a singleton. It could be null, or worth, create a memory leak.
You should pass the Context to the class constructor when you need it

If you want to throw an Exception at Runtime :

```
  private setField(String value) throws IllegalStateException {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Missing values");
// set your value here
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setContext(Context context){
```

should be

```
public synchronized void setContext(Context context){
```

And of course it assumes that a single client uses the class.
Otherwise you could overwrite the singleton state between thread calls and it seems rather inappropriate that one thread works with the context set by another tread (in a race condition case).

> Client need to pass context other wise app will crash at runtime. I
>   need to throw an error on compile time, if user does not set context.

A compiler is not designed to check the functional validation of the code.
It checks you respect the language rules and it is already very fine.

What you need is a runtime exeption that should be thrown if the user tries to manipulate the class while the context is not set.

To achieve it, you could do a check as first task in all public methods where the context is required.
Of course, you could create a private method and reuse it in each one of these places.

If the check fails, you throw a RuntimeException with the appropriate message.
If you want to really avoid to do these checks at many places, you can still use AOP.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

   //your statement here

} 

catch (RuntimeException ex) 

{

//do something with the runtime exception

}
```